# Undefined variable in create_function() parameter?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use create_function in order to find out how many times a certain value occurs in a particular array.

```
    while (!empty($rollcounts)){
        // Take the first element of $rollcounts

        $freq = count(array_filter($rollcounts,create_function("$a","return $a == $rollcounts[0]")));// Count how many times the first element of $rollcounts occurs in the list.

        $freqs[$rollcounts[0]] = $freq; // Add the count to the $frequencies list with associated number of rolls

        for($i=0;$i<count($rollcounts);$i++){ // Remove all the instances of that element in $rollcounts

            if(rollcounts[$i] == $rollcounts[0]){
                unset($rollcounts[$i]);
            }

        }

    } // redo until $rollcounts is empty
```

I get a "Notice" message complaining about the `$a` in `create_function()`. I'm surprised, because I thought `$a` was simply a parameter. Is `create_function()` not supported in my version of php? `phpversion()` returns 5.6.30 and I'm using XAMPP. The error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: a in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learningphp/myfirstfile.php on line 34
```

Comment: **Warning** This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Comment: try to use single quotes

Comment: **Caution** This function internally performs an eval() and as such has the same security issues as eval(). Additionally it has bad performance and memory usage characteristics.

___If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or newer a native anonymous function should be used instead.___

Comment: $a does not have a default value

Comment: You dont actually show how you create `$a` How do you do that

Comment: I don't create $a because I thought it was a parameter name.

Comment: You wouldn't create `$a` in `function($a){return a;}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I'm reading your question correctly, I think you want to count the occurrences of each element in the array? If so just use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) e.g. `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` -> `[1 => 2, 2 => 2, 3 => 1`]

```
$freqs = array_count_values($rollcounts);
```

This way you can skip your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like ...

```
$freq = count(array_filter($rollcounts,function($a) {return $a == $rollcounts[0];}));
```

Have a read of http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php which explains a bit more about them.